# SQL Force a column value based on a condition and group

Tags: sql

I have three columns on a SQL table:

```
Product ---- Flag 1 ---- Flag 2
Bike           1           0
Bike           1           1
Car            0           0
Car            0           0
```

I want to create another column that looks at Flag 2 and the Product; per each Product, if Flag 2 has a "1", give me all ones on those rows, if it has a "0", give me all zeros on those rows. Example:

```
 Product ---- Flag 1 ---- Flag 2 ---- Flag 3
 Bike           1           0           1
 Bike           1           1           1
 Car            0           0           0
 Car            0           0           0
```

I am basically trying to validate Flag 1 by creating the Flag on my own (Flag 2). But since I am dragging a couple of other columns and Flag 2 places "1" when certain conditions are met, when they aren't, it obviously places a zero, while Flag 1 is being pulled from another table (causing the "1" in all rows once the condition is met once). But afterwards, when I validate the "not okays" (when Flag 1 differs from Flag 2), I would basically get that 2nd row on this fake table as a NOK, which would be a mistake since I got it right for the "Bike" product (1st row).

I am sorry if this sounds confusing, just trying to give some context and not just asking for help. Thank you guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use window functions:

```
select t.*,
       max(flag2) over (partition by product) as flag3
from t;
```